# Is $\mathrm{End}(A) \cong A \otimes_k A^*$ for module $A$ over $k \in \mathsf{Comm}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $k$ be a commutative ring, and $A$ be a $k$-module. Does $\mathrm{End}(A) \cong A \otimes_k A^*$ hold in general? It holds for finite dimensional vector spaces, but I'm not sure how to construct an element of $A \otimes_k A^*$ that corresponds to $\mathrm{id}_A$ in general, without picking a basis.

Comment: Please make the body of your posts self-contained. The title is an indexing feature, and should not be an integral part of the message. Think of it as the title of a book on the spine; it's there to let people know what the post is about, not to impart information without which you cannot understand what is happening.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice that $\operatorname{End}(A)$ is never zero, unless $A$ is zero: the identity map is then a not-zero element. So one way to break the isomorphism is to pick a $k$ and $A$ so that the right hand side is zero. One way to do that is to have $A^*$ zero.

For example: let $k=\mathbb Z$ and let $A=\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$. As there is no linear map $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z$, we have $A^*=0$.

The isomorphism *does* work when $A$ is a finitely generated projective, though.

**Later**. This is treated, for example, in F. W. Anderson and K. R. Fuller's *Rings and categories of modules*, where it is Proposition 20.10. The general statement is:

> Let $R$, $S$ be two rings and let ${}_SP$, ${}_SU_T$ ${}_TN$ be modules. Then there is a $\mathbb Z$-linear map $$\phi_{P,T,N}:\hom_S(P,U)\otimes_TN\to\hom_S(P,U\otimes_TN)$$ which is natural in $P$, $U$ and $N$ (and in $R$ and $S$, in the appropriate sense!) which is an isomorphism if $P$ is a finitely generated projective. The map $\phi$ is uniquely determined by the condition that $$\phi_{P,T,N}(f\otimes n)(p)=f(p)\otimes n$$ for all $f\in\hom_S(P,U)$, $n\in N$ and $p\in P$.

You obtain the map in the question as the inverse of what you get from this statement by taking $S=T=k$, $P=N=A$ and $U=k$. The proof of the statement is easy. One first checks that for each choice of $P$, $U$, $N$ there is indeed a map $_{P,T,N}$ satisfying the condition mentioned in the last sentence, and that it is in fact natural; this is straightforward but a bit boring. If now $P$ is finitely generated and projective, there exists a ${}_SP'$ such that $P\oplus P'$ is finitely generated and free, isomorphic to $S^n$ for some $n\geq0$. Since the map $\phi$ is a natural transformation between *additive* functors of $P$, so show that $\phi_{P,T,N}$ is an isomorphism it is enough to show that $\phi_{P\oplus P',T,N}$, which is conjugate to $\phi_{S^n,T,N}$. Again, additivity implies that to show that $\phi_{S^n,T,N}$ is an isomorphism it is enough to show that the map $\phi_{S,T,N}$ is an isomorphism. And the latter is trivial.

Comment: Can you recommend a reference that deals with this isomorphism and its naturality in detail, please?

Comment: In the first sentence of the general statement, I believe $R$ and $T$ are supposed to be equal.